# argument to 'which' is not logical,grepl

Tags: r

```
Column_A            Column_B
lehman electronics  "simplifying technology home the lehman world is now digital."
levan group         "the levan group  \n \n      home   dlocation aspx \t"
life botanica       "of denton  txt life botanica"
```

I aim to match the first word of Colum_A with the entire string of Column_B,and if match's it returns "Match".

I've tried following code:

```
matchColumn <- function(dataColumn, searchColumn)
{ 
  desc <- searchColumn[which(grepl(unlist(strsplit(dataColumn," "))[1], searchColumn))]
  desc <- ifelse(length(desc) == 0, NA, "Match") 
  return(desc) 
}
file_new1$CombinationMatch <- sapply(file_new1$Column_A, matchColumn, file_new1$Column_B)
```

but it gives me weird error saying

> which(grepl(unlist(strsplit(dataColumn, " "))[1], searchColumn)) :
>   argument to 'which' is not logical

Comment: Try `Column_B` instead of `ColumnB`?

Comment: you actually don't need to use `which` to subset your data.frame. Also, you'll need to add something about the case, else "Lehman" will not match "lehman"

Comment: @ulfelder, my bad. try with Column_B

Comment: @Cath, done trying with that. The result is wrong,because inspite of no match it shows Match. i guess which is mandatory there. I'll make sure for the case problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version that returns what I think you're after:

```
matchColumn <- function(dataColumn, searchColumn) {

    # your indexing was off here 
    keyword <- sapply(strsplit(dataColumn, " "), function(i) i[1])

    # you don't need which here, but you do need ignore.case = TRUE
    desc <- sapply(seq_along(keyword), function(x) grepl(keyword[x], searchColumn[x], ignore.case = TRUE))

    ifelse(desc, "Match", NA) 

}
```

Then just:

```
file_new1$CombinationMatch <- with(file_new1, matchColumn(Column_A, Column_B))

> file_new1
           Column_A                                                     Column_B CombinationMatch
1 Leman Electronics simplifying technology home the lehman world is now digital.             <NA>
2       Levan Group          the levan group  \n \n      home   dlocation aspx \t            Match
3     life botanica                                 of denton  txt life botanica            Match
```

Comment: the just now modified one shows error of " subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Weird, I tested it and it worked here. Anyway, I've reverted to the earlier version.